# How can I control the output from gradle daemon

Tags: gradle, gradle-daemon

I am setting jvm args in my gradle build and it is giving me this mildly annoying message:

```
Note: in order to honour the org.gradle.jvmargs and/or org.gradle.java.home values specified for this build, it is necessary to fork a new JVM.
To avoid the slowdown associated with this extra process, you might want to consider running Gradle with the daemon enabled.
Please see the user guide chapter on the daemon at /Users/gus/tools/gradle-1.4/docs/userguide/gradle_daemon.html.
:compileJava UP-TO-DATE
:processResources UP-TO-DATE
:classes UP-TO-DATE
```

So wanting to make the message go away I tried `gradle --daemon`. Then I got hit with a boatload of spam that looked like this: (small excerpt)

```
14:33:35.248 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.launcher.daemon.client.DaemonClientConnection] thread 1: dispatching class org.gradle.launcher.daemon.protocol.Build
14:33:35.287 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.launcher.daemon.client.DaemonClientConnection] thread 1: received class org.gradle.launcher.daemon.protocol.BuildStarted
14:33:35.298 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.launcher.daemon.client.DaemonClientConnection] thread 1: received class org.gradle.logging.internal.ProgressStartEvent
14:33:35.316 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.launcher.daemon.client.DaemonClientConnection] thread 1: received class org.gradle.logging.internal.ProgressStartEvent
14:33:35.319 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.launcher.daemon.client.DaemonClientConnection] thread 1: received class org.gradle.logging.internal.ProgressCompleteEvent
14:33:35.321 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.launcher.daemon.client.DaemonClientConnection] thread 1: received class org.gradle.logging.internal.ProgressStartEvent
14:33:35.322 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.launcher.daemon.client.DaemonClientConnection] thread 1: received class org.gradle.logging.internal.ProgressCompleteEvent
14:33:35.444 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.launcher.daemon.client.DaemonClientConnection] thread 1: received class org.gradle.logging.internal.ProgressCompleteEvent
14:33:35.446 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.launcher.daemon.client.DaemonClientConnection] thread 1: received class org.gradle.logging.internal.ProgressStartEvent
14:33:35.447 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.launcher.daemon.client.DaemonClientConnection] thread 1: received class org.gradle.logging.internal.ProgressStartEvent
14:33:35.444 [LIFECYCLE] [org.gradle.TaskExecutionLogger] :compileJava
14:33:35.479 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.launcher.daemon.client.DaemonClientConnection] thread 1: received class org.gradle.logging.internal.ProgressStartEvent
14:33:35.649 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.launcher.daemon.client.DaemonClientConnection] thread 1: received class org.gradle.logging.internal.ProgressCompleteEvent
14:33:35.728 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.launcher.daemon.client.DaemonClientConnection] thread 1: received class org.gradle.logging.internal.ProgressCompleteEvent
14:33:35.727 [LIFECYCLE] [org.gradle.TaskExecutionLogger] :compileJava UP-TO-DATE
14:33:35.731 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.launcher.daemon.client.DaemonClientConnection] thread 1: received class org.gradle.logging.internal.ProgressStartEvent
14:33:35.727 [LIFECYCLE] [org.gradle.TaskExecutionLogger] :processResources
14:33:35.736 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.launcher.daemon.client.DaemonClientConnection] thread 1: received class org.gradle.logging.internal.ProgressCompleteEvent
14:33:35.735 [LIFECYCLE] [org.gradle.TaskExecutionLogger] :processResources UP-TO-DATE
14:33:35.739 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.launcher.daemon.client.DaemonClientConnection] thread 1: received class org.gradle.logging.internal.ProgressStartEvent
14:33:35.736 [LIFECYCLE] [org.gradle.TaskExecutionLogger] :classes
```

It was about 3 seconds faster, but That's substantially more annoying than the original message! How do I get rid of either the original message or get rid of all this logging output so that the output goes back to normal?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I don't see any such output. I've enabled the daemon using the property file method, maybe that's why?

**~/.gradle/gradle.properties:**

```
org.gradle.daemon=true
```

You can always use `gradle --no-daemon` if you decide one particular execution should ignore it.

Comment: Strange but true. Setting it in the properties file did the trick. Apparently passing in the command line flag turns on crazy logging. Never dreamed it would matter. Seems like a bug or misfeature. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Actually adding daemon method is similar for the following operating systems. For each of the following operating systems, create a file named "gradle.properties" in the following directories:

- /home/username/.gradle/ (Linux)
- /Users/username/.gradle/ (Mac)
- C:\Users\username\.gradle\ (Windows)

Add this line to the file:

> org.gradle.daemon=true